# Is there any easy way in scala to store method source code to some variable during compilation?

Tags: java, scala, compilation

I have a trait in scala framework

```scala
trait Expression {
  def evaluate(): Boolean

  // val evaluateSourceCode: String = "FILL_ME" // do I need it?
}
```

API users are going to implement this method. Is there any possibility get method implementation during compilation and save it as plain string to `evaluateSourceCode`? 
This thing should be bundled with my framework and be build tool agnostic. Users could go with maven / gradle / sbt / whatever.

Comment: Why do you need the source code of the implementation?

Comment: one of usecases - need to show `evaluate` source code to enduser user web interface

Comment: perhaps https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode would help here?